# Animating a subplot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create animate  3 subplots displaying different y axes w.r.t time(x-axis). Please refer to the code below.

[image: Check Image for Code]

On running the code I am getting the below error

**AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'canvas'**

Comment: From next time, please try to copy and paste the code onto the StackOverflow website, it can be hard to read from an image like this. Also please try mentioning the exact line where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

[`plt.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) returns the Axes object, not the figure object. You can get the figure by using [`plt.gcf()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gcf.html) (gcf = Get current figure).